# Register without required Schema.Types.ObjectId

Tags: node.js

the relation is working correctly but the requerid does not work for me, even if it is true

```
const UsuariosSchema = new Schema({
nombre_completo: { type:String, required:true },
apellido_paterno:{ type:String, required:true },
apellido_materno:{ type:String, required:true },
roles:[
        {type:Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:'roles', required:true}
    ],
email:{ type:String, required:true },   
contrasenia:{ type:String, required:true },},{ timestamps: true });
```

[Attached a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n4SRU.png)

Comment: please update with code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course it doesn't work, you are not making the `roles` (which is a list) `required` by that statement. Instead, you are setting `required` for each item in that list. If every item in that list is required, how many of them are you requiring? All of them (infinity)?

If you need a single role then drop the list and make it a single attribute.

```
role: {type:Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:'roles', required:true}
```

If you need to specify more (but specific) roles then just add them each one as an attribute

```
role1: {type:Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:'roles', required:true}
role2: {type:Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:'roles', required:true}
```

If you want to specify arbitrary number of roles (using list) then again, `required` doesn't make much sense.